# How do I avoid unwanted assignment in loops when using comparison operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, logical-operators

This is my code which iterates and takes inputs as the number and when user input "done", it comes out of loop and print smallest and largest of the input numbers.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
num = input("Enter a number: ")
if num == "done" : 
    break
try:
    a = int(num)
except:
    print("Invalid input")
if largest is None:
    largest = num
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
if smallest > num:
    smallest = num
if largest < num:
    largest = num  
print(smallest, largest)    #for dry run
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Now my problem is whenever I input a non-number such as ***bob***, it gets assigned to largest and print maximum number as ***bob***.

Comment: Looks like the indenting got messed up. You can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: Move the `if` statements to inside the `try` block so they only get executed if no exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) - tl;dr use `continue` if you get invalid input

Comment: BTW, you can simplify: `if largest is None or largest < num: largest = num`

Comment: Or even: `largest = max(a, largest) if largest else a`

Comment: @Johnny That will fail on `largest = 0`. Fixed: `largest = max(a, largest) if largest is not None else a`

Comment: @wjandrea True.

Answer (score 2):

You are *acknowledging* that `int(num)` failed, but then using the value of `num` (rather than `a`) anyway. You could continue the loop instead. With correct indentation, your code should look something like

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done": 
        break

    try:
        a = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None:
        largest = a
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = a
    if smallest > a:
        smallest = a
    if largest < a:
        largest = a  

print(smallest, largest)    #for dry run
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: You can also simplify: `if largest is None or largest < a: largest = a`

Comment: whoops, sorry, that comment was meant for OP

Comment: Even better, just initialize `largest = -float('inf')` and `smallest = float('inf')`. Then you don't need any special cases.